# gcc equivalent of #pragma comment

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

I'm trying to write a macro that adds a comment to an executable with the gcc compiler. This is not for linking purposes, I simply want to add text comments. Is there a #pragma comment equivalent in gcc for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what it means to "add a comment to an executable".  Who or what is going to consume, display, or even notice such comments?  Nevertheless, if you just want to ensure some string is embedded somewhere in your program, then simply declare it as an ordinary (C) string at file scope.

```
static const char my_comment[] = "This comment should appear in the compiled executable";
```

Comment: I think I'm asking the wrong question, but I'll accept this answer as it does adequately address what I asked

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to clutter the `.data` section (which is where the `static const char[]` would go) with comments or conversely, want the comments to be found easily from the `.comment` section, you can add the comments there with a little bit of inline assembly:

```
__asm__(".section .comment\n\t"
        ".string \"Hello World\"\n\t"
        ".section .text");
```

Gcc also [has](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Other-Directives.html) `#ident` directive which copies the text into an appropriate section if available. In the case of ELF, it would be the .comment section. This solution, even though the directive isn't standard, is probably more portable than the former.

```
#ident "Hello World"
```

Comment: If this were successful, would it be apparent that there was extra binary after the ".comment" in the object file?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. This code would add the string "Hello World" to the .comment section as text. Gcc already generates it's own version string into that section by default.

Comment: In the AIX 6.0.1 world, use `.csect .comment[RO]` instead of `.section .comment` and use `.csect .text[PR]` instead of `.section .text` as the compiler, assembler and linker are older than you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

#ident may be useful. But there are two caveats :

1. It may not work on all targets.
2. This is neither a C language standard nor a GNU coding standard

> The ‘#ident’ directive takes one argument, a string constant. On some
>   systems, that string constant is copied into a special segment of the
>   object file. On other systems, the directive is ignored. The ‘#sccs’
>   directive is a synonym for ‘#ident’.
>
> These directives are not part of the C standard, but they are not
>   official GNU extensions either.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Other-Directives.html