# How to write informations needed in an executable file

Tags: gcc, compilation, comments, executable, xlc

I wanted to know if you knew a command or a way to write as comment or string inside of the executable file.
Indeed I already did this, with *XLC* compiler I did it with the `#pragma comment(user, "string")` however now I have to change to *GCC* but there's a problem, under *GCC* this `#pragma` is not recognized.

My question is, do you know another `#pragma` who can do it under gcc, or just another way to process to recover an information written in the executable file when I compile.

Thanks, Ežekiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution.String literals in a c/c++ program, are usually put into the read-only segment of the ELF file.

Assuming that your comment follows a pattern:

```
My_Comment: ....
```

you could add some string definitions in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    char* a = "My Comment: ...";
}
```

compile:

```
$ gcc test.c
```

and then search for your comment pattern in the executable:

```
$ strings a.out | grep Comment
My Comment: ...
```

may I ask what is the use case of embedding comments into an executable?

Follow up:

If you are compiling with the -O3 flag, this unused string is optimized out, so it is not stored at all in the ro data. Based on the same idea, you could fool gcc by:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    FILE* comment = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    fprintf(comment, "My Comment:");
}
```

Then search for your comment. You get the overhead of 2 or 3 system calls of course, but hopefully you can live with it.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Sure you can ask, I want to do this because I have to recover the version of each source file contained in the executable to ease the debugging when there are differents versions. And I tried your way, it's not working :(

Comment: Are u sure that you did not make any typo in the grep command? Can you paste the output of the strings command? What is the OS that you are working with? Some Linux distribution I suppose?

Comment: I work on AIX, the problem with your method is that's too complicated for non-experienced guys in C to apply this inside of each source file indeed my solution was easier just puting a comment in each file, but if we have to modify a function inside of the code, (who must be called and declared etc) you can see that my option was easier. That's why I asked if the equivalent in gcc is existing.

Comment: I ultimately decided on a declaration like: cont char*test=":My text version:"; who will be situated in the head of each source file, and I parse the binary with a cat -v then with tr ':' '\n' to cut the output lines where there's a ':' to isolate the pattern that I finally grep ("My text" for example here). Thanks

Comment: @Ežekiel - check the AIX command `man what` for details, but the `const char* ver = "@(#) version details";` is exactly what the `what` program is looking for, displaying everything after the `@(#)` prefix string.  Originally the SCCS command `get` was used to insert this string into the source files as it fetched them from the source control database.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put some specific information in the executable using the **xlC_r** family of compiler on AIX, is

```
#pragma comment(copyright, "whatever")
```

If you want a **what** style string, then I recommend:

```
// the Q(S) macro uses ANSI token pasting to get the _value_
// of the macro argument as a string.
#define Q(S) Q_(S)
#define Q_(S) #S
// breaking up the "@(" and "#)" prevent `what` from finding this source file.
#define WHAT(MODULE,VERSION) "@(" "#) " Q(VERSION) " " Q(MODULE) " " __DATE__ " " __TIME__
#pragma comment(copyright, WHAT(ThisProgram,1.2.3.4))
```

Or whatever special string you are embedding.

UPDATE: for **gcc**

See answer by user2079303 at: [gcc equivalent of #pragma comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572356/gcc-equivalent-of-pragma-comment)

To use inline assembler to add a string to the **.comment** section

```
__asm__(".section .comment\n\t"
        ".string \"Hello World\"\n\t"
        ".section .text");
```

UPDATE: for AIX **gcc**

It seems this work better on AIX gcc inline assembler to add a string to the **.comment** section

```
__asm__(".csect .comment[RO]\n\t"
        ".string \"Hello World\"\n\t"
        ".csect .text[PR]");
```